# Almacenar en caché HTML modificado

Tags: javascript, html, cache

Quisiera saber si existe algún modo de que se cacheé  una pagina HTML cuyo **body** a cambiado por ejemplo de:

```
<body></body>
```

a

```
<body><span>Body cambiado</span></body>
```

Este body puede cambiar por diferentes causas. Cuando el usuario vuelva a solicitar la página, sería necesario que se cargara la página con el **body** cambiado.

¿Existe algún modo para ello?¿Debo modificar la cabecera o hacerlo manualmente con JavaScript?

Muchísimas gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de HTML y JavaScript que modifica el contenido de la página? Esto debería hacerse a nivel de un [Servicio de Trabajadores (Service Worker)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). Échale un vistazo a la documentación que te he proporcionado y si tienes alguna duda adapta la pregunta para ello o deja un comentario.

Comment: Realmente no quería llegar eso. Es decir, primero quiero explorar si existe esta opción tal cual. Da igual si se modifica por contenido dinámico o incluso a través de un plugin del navegador o con un botón que modifique un texto. Si existe la posibilidad de mandar a cache el documento html actual, ahorraría todo lo demás. No obstante gracias por la aportación, la estoy leyendo.

Comment: El código JavaScript que se ejecuta en el navegador no puede alterar el contenido de la caché del navegador, pero el uso de service workers abre la posibilidad de interceptar las peticiones HTTP realizadas por una página web y guardarlas en un almacenamiento caché. Aquí tienes la interfaz de caché y algunos ejemplos de uso: [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).